# Is $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$ the same as $a\times d \;<\; c\times b$ for positive integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Is
$$\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$$.
same as
$$a\times d \;<\; c\times b$$
if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are positive integers?

Can someone verify this?

Comment: Yes, in fact it is enough that the product $bd$ is positive (i.e. that $b$ and $d$ are of the same sign) as you can convert one inequality to the other by multiplying/dividing both sides by $bd>0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually I know this is true, but I'm not confident at mathematics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is true for positive integers. Multiplying both sides by $b\times d$ proves this. Conversely, dividing the product inequality by $b\times d$ gives back the inequality of ratios.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $b\times d$ only proves one direction. To prove the other direction multiply by their multiplicative inverses (which exist and are positive since $b$ and $d$ are positive).

Comment: @CarlaCvekla, Edited to include that.